# Not Receiving push on pre-4.4 KitKat device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM InstanceID Class  to generate the token.it is working fine on 5.0 or above device but  on pre-4.4 KitKat device i am not getting the push through gcm.

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eliteappcreations.shouldigo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <permission android:name="com.eliteappcreations.shouldigo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.eliteappcreations.shouldigo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:name=".ShouldIGoApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/debug_facebook_app_id" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.eliteappcreations.shouldigo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".service.gcmservice.GcmNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".service.gcmservice.NotificationInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".service.gcmservice.TokenRegistrationIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Service**

```
 @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "service started");

        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(TokenRegistrationIntentService.this);
        try {
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_sender_id),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
            Log.i(TAG, token);

            if (token != null) {
                sendRegistrationTokenToServer(token);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
```

[click here for documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: Are you getting any error ? If any, can you post your logcat..

Comment: @Umesh i don't know if its just an error when you posted the question but your TokenRegistrationIntentService declaration in the manifest is not properly closed.

Comment: There is no need to call `stopSelf();` in `onHandleIntent` it's `IntentService` not simply `Service`

Answer (score 1):

You can set `delay_while_idle` flag to `false` in server side for working GCM push message service below Lollipop.

**delay_while_idle**

*If included, indicates that the message should not be sent immediately if the device is idle. The server will wait for the device to become active, and then only the last message for each collapse_key value will be sent. Optional. The default value is false, and must be a JSON boolean.*

See the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/CimKwgaf2ws) for more

Comment: i am not receiving push on below kitkat devices.

Comment: yes I said below Lollipop, Have u tried it in server ?